# Magento 2 UI form set default value from url params?

Tags: magento2, ui-form

I want to set a form field value from the URL params in UI form. I am aware that static values can be set via `default` property of the `field` but how to set dynamic values as default (to be specific request URL params).

Also, what is the standard way to do it?

```
`http://localhost/magento/2.2.4/admin/mymodule/myform/edit/type/vendor/`
```

Here, `type/vendor` the value vendor needs to be set on `type` field as `default`.

```
<field name="type">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">MyModule\MyVendor\Model\Source\Type</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">mymodule_myform_form_data_source</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Type</item>
                <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="string">inventory</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

> MyModule\MyVendor\Model\Source\Type.php

```
<?php

namespace MyModule\MyVendor\Model\Source;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource;

class Type extends AbstractSource
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        return [
            [
                'value' => 'vendor',
                'label' => __('Vendor'),
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

[image: form]

Comment: why not set it on your source type since data coming from there

Comment: can you post `MyModule\MyVendor\Model\Source\Type` codes

Comment: Datasource works only if there is data i.e the form is editing a saved value.
In the case of new form, the values are ignored as there is no `id` for it.

Answer (score 1):

This is untested but you can give it a try.
In your **Type.php** class, inject `\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request` to get the value of the parameter **`type`** in the **`URL`** which is the value **`vendor`**.

```
<?php

namespace MyModule\MyVendor\Model\Source;

class Type implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    protected $request;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    )
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $type = $this->request->getParam('type');

        return [
            [
                'value' => $type,
                'label' => __('Vendor'),
            ],
        ];

    }
}
```

In that way, you are setting the value of options from the URL parameter.

Comment: This looks a little out of the way.
It may be working as UI form takes the first field, but then I need to update labels too.

Comment: Is label the same with the value? I mean the text of the label? or it will be taken from somewhere else